# Elasticsearch error "failed to find nested object under path"

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I know this has been asked multiple times before but none of the existing questions or answers have helped me.

I am getting the following error when querying Elasticsearch:

> [nested] failed to find nested object under path [departures]

The query I am running is below:

```
{
    "explain":true,
    "from":0,
    "query":{
        "nested":{
            "path":"departures",
            "query":{
                "term":{
                    "departures.yearMonth":{
                        "value":202007
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "size":20
}
```

And my mapping is as follows:

```
{
    "tours":{
        "mappings":{
            "properties":{
                "departures":{
                    "type":"nested",
                    "properties":{
                        "guaranteed":{
                            "type":"boolean"
                        },
                        "spacesRemaining":{
                            "type":"long"
                        },
                        "startDate":{
                            "type":"date"
                        },
                        "yearMonth":{
                            "type":"long"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And finally, a screenshot taken from Kibana showing that there is a valid entry in my index.
[image]

Any ideas why this query would be failing like this?

Comment: What version are you using?

Comment: Are you querying indices that do not have the `nested` field mapping?

Comment: @AlkisKalogeris Version is 7.5.2.

Comment: @RussCam In the mapping I posted in above, the type is nested.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try setting the `ignore_unmapped` flag to true on your query request

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-nested-query.html

> ignore_unmapped
>   (Optional, boolean) Indicates whether to ignore an unmapped path and not return any documents instead of an error. Defaults to false.
>
> If false, Elasticsearch returns an error if the path is an unmapped field.
>
> You can use this parameter to query multiple indices that may not contain the field path.

Comment: Strange. So that stopped the error but is now not returning the expected results which suggests there's a mapping issue. However, the mapping I have posted clearly shows that the `departures` field is mapped as a `nested` type. Any ideas what might be going on here or suggestions to fix?

Comment: Your mapping doesn't prevent the indexing of a document that has other fields. Check this https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/dynamic.html . You can try changing your setting to `strict` so it throws when try to save something "different" from what you've specified. Is this a testing environment? Can you try that?

Comment: Thanks a lot for the advice. This was not a test environment and I didn't actually have one as I've only recently started using Elastic. However, I set up a test environment and recreated my index with strict mapping and made sure everything was mapped correctly and I've now got a working search. Just need to rebuild the production environment and then hopefully I'm sorted. Thanks again for your guidance.

Comment: Hi @AndyFurniss, happy I could help. If it's not a bother, you can mark the answer. Have fun.